# C++ random fixed set of strings

Tags: c++, random

So creating a poker game and I have a random number generator set up, now just want to generate a random string between "C", "S", "H", and "D" (obvious reasons). I looked a bit on SO and did not find exactly what I'm looking for, I did find a random string generator in C, but it was out of all of the letters, and you could not make it any more specific. I would post code that I have tried, but I haven't even gotten a foundation for how this will work.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget to mention that I've done this with an array and would like to not use that (if possible). I am learning about structs so any way that would be relevant with that would be better.

Comment: Roll a number between 0 and 3, and take C if 0, S if 1, and so on? You could put C,S,H and D into an array and roll its index. Or is that what you mean with "not using an array"?

Comment: first way would work, i would just need to make sure it's actually random. Any way to do that other than srand? (from what I've heard it's not very random). 

EDIT nevermind, that's for me to research :) thanks for the idea man

Comment: @user3308129 -- I don't understand why you would design the game around picking between suits.  Wouldn't you want to pick a random card out of 52 (not including jokers)?

Comment: There are plenty of random generators for C++, some of them are cryptically secure. Google them, that's not the scope of this question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have it picking a number, it now needs to pick a suit (it's a Console C++ with GUI.. forgot to mention that). The suit has to be a string.

Comment: @user3308129 - Why separating suit from number?  Just create a struct that has both, store 52 of them in an array, and call std::random_shuffle()

Comment: @JiaYow if you want to post a comment I'll up-check it for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am creating the logic for the struct now, it does have the number in there, I just need it to randomly select a string now for the suit. I see what you're saying, and I may do that at some point, but this would be a lot less work.

Comment: While I answered your question, I think @PaulMcKenzie's answer will in the end be more helpful to you, since it's the cleaner solution overall. You should accept his answer.

Comment: @user3308129 - How is it a lot less work?  You now have to keep track that you don't have more than 13 clubs, hearts, diamonds, etc.  My solution doesn't require you to keep track of this.  Back in the Wild West days, you would get shot for having a poker game the way you are envisioning...

Comment: Okay, sorry I am fairly new, I will just try your way out, it does make sense what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a poker game, first define the struct that has both suit and number:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Card
{
    int number;
    std::string suit;
};
//...
std::vector<Card> MyCards(52);
// write some code to initialize each card with their values
//...
```

Now when you have this, then this is how you shuffle the cards:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::random_shuffle(MyCards.begin(), MyCards.end());
```

There is a 3 argument version of random_shuffle() that takes a custom random generator if you don't like the default.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: ok thanks man, this helps a lot and makes complete sense. I really appreciate it.